# Как добавить звук в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу чтобы, после того как пользователь ввёл число через input появлялась музыка

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/

Comment: А что делать если не работает воспроизведение? Я установил всё правильно, но он просто выводит текст, но,однако, не говорит его

Comment: код пожалуйста приложите